# Asynchronous processing using AJAX and .net Web Service

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asynchronous

I'm stuck with this problem for quite some time. Advise needed...

Alright i have this ASPX test-service page(AJAX)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {      
        $('#btnTest').click(function () {
            $('#btnTest').hide();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "request.asmx/newSync",
                data: '',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                complete: function () {
                    $('#btnTest').show();
                },
                failure: function (msg) {
                    $('#result').text(msg);
                    //alert(msg);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The Web Service

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

[ScriptService]
public class test_request : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

public test_request () {


}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public SyncAsync newSync()
{
    var response = new SyncAsync();

    //Test Processing
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

    try
    {
        response.Status = "Done";
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.Status = "error";
        response.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
    }

    return response;
}

}
```

Okay my Question is this...Is this Asynchronous?...Meaning when i click the button it sends the request and i shall not wait for any response back from the webservice...?

Can someone explain?

Thank you

Comment: Your javascipr is async, it will not block on sending the request and it will fire `complete` or `failure` callbacks when the response comes back.

Comment: Note it is `error:` and not `failure:` for any ajax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is async and is all handled for you :)

Your ajax call returns immediately after queuing the request.

It's specified `complete:` callback gets called when the response returns from the server, or `error:` (not `failure`) if an error occurs on the server.

in the meantime your browser/client code has been busy processing multiple execution loops.

Comment: Thanks @TrueBlueAussie. Correct me if i'm wrong. This is my scenario, I'm suppose to calculate yearly billings. Alright, now once i click the run button, a request has already been made meaning it will run the billing in the background right(i havent add the codes here, let's imagine)? Is this correct?

Comment: @Gopinath Koothaperumal: Yes. If you use a tool like Fiddler2 or the Chrome F12 network panel, you can see the timing of the request/response is "relatively" slow (takes a significant fraction of a second) but the client browser code just keeps on running.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding we need to define Asynchronous what?
Request or Web Service

to make async call from jquery you need to set ajax settings. 
Async is true  by default.

to make Async Web Service you need to implement 
IAsyncResult BeginOperation 
object EndOperation 
methods for your service

So my idea is that your Web Service is synchronous, but ajax requests are async.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, jQuery ajax calls are asynchronous by default.

If you need synchronous requests, set async option to false:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {      
    $('#btnTest').click(function () {
        $('#btnTest').hide();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: false
            url: "request.asmx/newSync",
            data: '',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            complete: function () {
                $('#btnTest').show();
            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                $('#result').text(msg);
                //alert(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Never, repeat *never*, suggest `async: false` as a solution *to anything*. Always encourage working with the *async* default pattern :)

Comment: Yes I know and you're right, but it's an option there, he did not know how jQuery ajax calls work and this is an option for them